# Importing Pywinauto causes debug messages to appear twice

Tags: python, logging, pywinauto

I have an old python script that uses logging that I have just been updating by adding pywinauto.

Any log lines are written as expected to the log file but once pywinauto is imported I get 2 copies of the line written to the console.

Commenting out the import pywinauto line fixes the problems (but is not a real solution as I need to make use of the library)

```
import logging
import pywinauto

# Set up a script_logger.
script_logger = logging.getLogger('test')
script_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

script_logger.addHandler(ch)

logFilename = "debug.log"
fh = logging.FileHandler(logFilename)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
script_logger.addHandler(fh)
script_logger.debug("Hello world")
```

Typical output (first line expected, second line not)

```
2016-12-15 17:43:09,056 - test - DEBUG - Hello world
2016-12-15 17:43:09,056 DEBUG: Hello world
```

I can see that the second line is created within

> Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\actionlogger.py

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: It might be a bug in pywinauto. Thanks for reporting this. Unfortunately will take a look at this after the New Year.

Comment: Any idea when this might get looked at? Should I raise a ticket on pywinauto?

Comment: Just went back from the holidays trip. Will take a look soon. There is also another issue with comtypes warnings while importing pywinauto.

Comment: Created bug report here: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/312 Will fix in pywinauto 0.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

Now it should be fixed in master branch. Can you try it with `pip install https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/archive/master.zip`?